# Making a match between two variables from different data frames and showing others variables from both data frames

Tags: r

I have a little problem with two data frames like these: Fist data frame

```
     Num.Op     Bonus
    381942        Y
    382181        Z
    382260        A
    382266        A
```

And second data frame:

```
    Num.Op1     Site
    381942  Ecua Auto S.A.
    382181  Vallejo Araujo S.A.
    382260  Automotores de la Sierra
    382266  Automotores de la Sierra
    382310  Vallejo Araujo S.A.
    382619  Vallejo Araujo S.A.
```

I would like to create a new data frame where, after of making a comparison between the variable `Num.Op` from data frame one and the variable `Num.Op1` from second data frame, I show two variables: first is `Num.Op1` from second data frame and second is `v1`, `v1` will take a valor of 1 if a element from `Num.Op` is in `Num.Op1` and 0 if isn't, and for all cases that have 1 also the variables `site` and `bonus` should be showed. Something like this:

```
   Num.Op1   v1  Site                        Bonus
    381942    1  Ecua Auto S.A.                Y
    382181    1  Vallejo Araujo S.A.           Z
    382260    1  Automotores de la Sierra      A
    382266    1  Automotores de la Sierra      A
    382310    0  NA                            NA
    382619    0  NA                            NA
```

I prove with match but I don't get the result.

Comment: `merge` with all.y=TRUE

Comment: Also we can't read that data in easily.  Please use dput to provide the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use the `merge` function.

First, create a new column 'v1' for your first data frame and fill it with '1':

```
df1$v1 <- 1
```

Then you create a new data.frame by merging your 2 original data frames together:

```
mergedDF <- merge(df1, df2, by=1, all.y=TRUE)
```

Finally, you assign '0' to the values in the v1 column that are not already '1':

```
mergedDF$v1[is.na(mergedDF$v1)] <- 0
```

mergedDF should now contain what you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
# input data
df1 = read.table(text = ' Num.Op     Bonus
 381942        Y
 382181        Z
 382260        A
 382266        A', header = T)
df2 = read.table(text = '    Num.Op1     Site
    381942  "Ecua Auto S.A."
    382181  "Vallejo Araujo S.A."
    382260  "Automotores de la Sierra"
    382266  "Automotores de la Sierra"
    382310  "Vallejo Araujo S.A."
    382619  "Vallejo Araujo S.A."', header = T)

# load data.table, convert to data.table and set keys for merging
library(data.table)
dt1 = data.table(df1, key = "Num.Op")
dt2 = data.table(df2, key = "Num.Op1")

# the merge - add a v1 column to dt1, merge with dt2, whenever the merge fails,
# i.e. v1 is NA, set v1 to 0 and Site to NA (Bonus will be set to NA automatically)
result = dt1[, v1 := 1][dt2][is.na(v1), `:=`(v1 = 0, Site = NA_character_)]
result
#   Num.Op Bonus v1                     Site
#1: 381942     Y  1           Ecua Auto S.A.
#2: 382181     Z  1      Vallejo Araujo S.A.
#3: 382260     A  1 Automotores de la Sierra
#4: 382266     A  1 Automotores de la Sierra
#5: 382310    NA  0                       NA
#6: 382619    NA  0                       NA
```